# how to sum the sales by child in this google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a project for local children's org.  We have charity sales data in the following format in Google sheet:

[image]

How can I create total sales by child from this table above? I want the output to be like this:

[image]

I've tried to use Query but couldn't get it right.  Please help!  Thank you!

Comment: In your first picture, wouldn't the 'Sales by Child' column actually be Sales by Event?

Comment: I should note in my first table the column "Sales by Child" should be more appropriately called "Sales per Child".  We have events where more than one child volunteers, so the total proceeds from the event are divided equally amount participating children...

Comment: Okay so the total sales by child will basically be, "which events did this child participate in, and what was the sales by child amount there. then sum all of the events"? Right?

Comment: @pat, yes that's correct.  I want to sum over all events by child, e.g., Child A made $100 sales from Event 1, and $250 from Event 3, so Child A's total sales will be $350 in total...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Child 1-4 column is not expected to expand, then I would just use sumif functions to get the sum of each column based on the child's letter.  Then add all to get the result for each letter child.  Then you will list all the letters in one column, copy the result column down.  Make sure to lock your cells for the sumif formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  Didn't know sumif is so powerful!